# If Model A has_many Instances of B, through another model C, how might I make a route to destroy an instance of B on a particular instance of A?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So forgive me if my title was a little unclear; I tried to make it as generic as possible.

I have a model `User`, a `ChatRoom` model and a `ChatRoomUser` model (which has no controller).  `User` has a `has_many` relationship with `ChatRoom`, through the `ChatRoomUser`, and vice versa.

I want to make a route to allow the user to leave one of the chat rooms; I have the code to handle the actual leaving of the room, in the `UsersController`:

```
def leave
    @chosen = ChatRoom.find(params[:chat_room_id])

    if @chosen.nil?
        redirect_back(fallback_location: chat_room_path(@chosen))
    end

    current_user.chat_rooms.remove(@chosen)

    # If there are no users left in the room, destroy it.
    if(!@chosen.users.any?)
        @chosen.destroy
    end

    redirect_to chat_rooms_path
end
```

and I think that's fine.  But I'm unclear as to how to properly set up a route for this.  I have in my routes file:

```
delete '/users/chat_room/:chat_room_id', to: 'users#leave'
```

but I have no idea how to refer to this in an html.erb file.  I've tried `<%= link_to users_chat_room_path(@chatroom), method: :delete %>` but no dice.

Should I perhaps make a controller for the ChatRoomUsers and make a destroy method on that to handle this?  I don't know if that's good practice (making a controller just for a single method).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes can be given custom names like this:

```
delete '/users/chat_room/:chat_room_id', 
       to: 'users#leave',
       as: :leave_room
```

Now it's available as `leave_room_path`.

> Should I perhaps make a controller for the ChatRoomUsers and make a destroy method on that to handle this? I don't know if that's good practice (making a controller just for a single method).

That is what REST advocates would tell you to do. A controller for just one method is not a bad practice. Bloating your controllers - that's bad practice. Controllers should be as skinny as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to how you might do this RESTfully, and given the object your deleting is a `chat_room_user` and the only param is `:id` on a `chat_room`:

In routes, nest a 'resource' under `chat_room` for `chat_room_user`.

```
resources :chat_room do
  resource :chat_room_user, :only => [:create, :delete]
end
```

Then in the `chat_room_users` controller

```
def create
  @chat_room = ChatRoom.find_by_id(params[:chat_room_id])
  # current_user join a chat room
end

def delete
  @chat_room = ChatRoom.find_by_id(params[:chat_room_id])
  # current_user leave a chat room
end
```

In the view, you'd refer to this route as `chat_room_chat_room_user_path(@chat_room)` and add the method: `:method => :delete` or `:method => :post`.